# Loading Addressable Sprites using their Address

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have followed this document from first to last to do practice with Addressable Sprites.

[Addressables: Sprite Loading](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/addressables-sprite-loading#5fb9665aedbc2a001fc450d0)

I can able to get success in Sprite loading through Addressables but when I try with specified Address, I am getting an exception like this:

[image]

Here are the addressable groups, I have created:
[image]

Now Image is not loading through a specific address:

> Assets/Resources_moved/CityLights/Images/Cities/Charlotte.png

Please share your suggestion regarding this.

**EDIT:** Expanded Addressible Groups
[image]

Comment: Expand the item in the addressable groups window, and make sure the addressable name matches the string exactly.

Comment: Please, Sir, I have uploaded one more image with expanded addressable groups

Comment: You need to load it using "Charlotte[Charlotte]", as that is the address.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as i can see in your screenshot that there is no image in that image component in unity inspector , so trace it first that is the particular image which you looking for is loading or not?? while it's running dynamicly check it first, and after it check the key value address of this particular addresable sprite from script while it running on unity.